# Excel VBA to open Sharepoint folder and create list of hyperlinks for files within

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

Prior to being asked to migrate to SharePoint, I was using a collection of .xlsm files to set project teams up to manage projects. My Project Manager file included a macro that would go to a designated folder and create hyperlinks for all current project files. I've saved the collection of .xlsm files on SharePoint, but when I run the macro below (which I found here - Thank you!), I receive an error related to the "Set xFolder = xFSO.GetFolder(xPath)" line. Any help would be great. I've read several posting that may have the answer and tried several adjustments to the code, with no luck.

```
Sub Create_Hyperlinks_for_all_Current_Projects()

Range("B8:D38").Clear

MsgBox "Once you click OK, an explorer box will appear. Select the folder 
containing all the CSTPs and then click OK again. HINT: The folder 
containing all the CSTPs should be in the same folder this document was in 
and should be called ''CSTPs''. Links to all CSTPs will then appear in the 
white box on the Manager Menu."
Dim xFSO As Object
Dim xFolder As Object
Dim xFile As Object
Dim xFiDialog As FileDialog
Dim xPath As String
Dim I As Integer
Set xFiDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With xFiDialog
.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path
End With
If xFiDialog.Show = -1 Then
    xPath = xFiDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If

Set xFiDialog = Nothing
If xPath = "" Then Exit Sub
Set xFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xFolder = xFSO.GetFolder(xPath)
For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
    I = I + 2
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(I + 6, 2), xFile.Path, , , xFile.Name
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: why would you keep the details about the error to yourself ?

Comment: What's the value of xPath when it fails?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you find the following notes helpful.
They summarize the outcomes from several weeks of frustration.

If you are using SP365,
then the filesystemobject 
no longer works very well, if at all.

I had hundreds of macros dependent on the FSO.
These have all worked great up until my organization migrated to SP365 :o(

Now they only work if I manually click 
the Open Explorer button, in SP, first.

Opening Explorer provides Win Explorer with the required permissions to access SP.
This in turn provides the FSO with the required permissions to access SP.

But...in my case...FSO only works for a while.

For my first work around...

I rolled out a prototype app, which used a macro to automate 
opening IE, opening Win Explorer and initializing permissions for the FSO

All worked great on my machine, for about an hour, 
then some kind of timeout took me back to square one.

Colleagues on other machines experienced a range of FSO behaviours.
From all working ok. To having to rerun the connection macro every 30 seconds.
To nothing working at all.

I then invested time trying to update macros to connect to SP as a network drive.
Again, this is a process that I have used for years, up until migration to SP365.
Again, success connecting to SP365 seems to be very machine dependent.

In the end...with respect to my own requirements...

My work around was to create an SP view that lists all files.
Then use the Export to Excel option in SP to create an Excel data query.
Then copy the query into an Excel file that I refer to as Config.xlsx.
Then use Excel RefreshAll to update the list of files, each time a list is required.

Its not very elegant...but, it works ;o)

As I say....I hope this helps you / someone.

Feel free to connect on LinkedIn if you require any followup advice.

Peter,

LinkedIn name DrPeterEHSmee

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).